# worpress page template hyperlink

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

i just want to know how to use a tag to link to my page template ?

i create a page template named `template-blogall.php` with this name: `<?php /* Template Name: blog all */ ?>`

i want to create `<a href="my template url">blog</a>` and use it in my `index.php`

i searched a lot and couldn't find any solution
i tried

```
add_action('init', function() {
  $url_path = trim(parse_url(add_query_arg(array()), PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
  if ( $url_path === 'retail' ) {
     // load the file if exists
     $load = locate_template('template-retail.php', true);
     if ($load) {
        exit(); // just exit if template was found and loaded
     }
  }
});
```

thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this page for the different ways to add templates - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/

Answer (score 0):

solution is :
i create the page in my panel and use the slug like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_site_url().'/load-more-posts'; ?>">More Posts</a>
```